# Flat file read- line to columns R

Tags: r, flat-file

I have a .txt file with the following data:

```
PSAP_Agency

Public Safety 

Char(120)    

PSAP_ID      

Pitney Bowes 

Integer
```

I need to read this in R with the structure:

```
column      desc           type
PSAP_Agency Public Safety  Char(120)
PSAP_ID     Pitney Bowes   Integer
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Is `PSAP_ID` always a single digit integer? If so you could use `read.fwf(filename, widths = c(120, 1))`.

Answer (score 3):

Considering your text file has the data in sequences of 3 lines with empty lines between them:

```
PSAP_Agency

Public Safety 

Char(120)    

PSAP_ID      

Pitney Bowes 

Integer
```

The following code reads data from the file and transforms it to the desired data frame structure:

```
text_file_name <- "text.txt" #path to the text file
number_of_columns <- 3
txt <- readLines(text_file_name)
txt <- txt[txt != ""] #removing empty lines
lst <- split(txt, as.integer(gl(length(txt), number_of_columns, length(txt))))
df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lst))
names(df) <- c("column", "desc", "type")
print(df)
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Yes it does!! Thank you !! :)